# Best way to allow users to enter in information into a limited character cell in a table

Tags: usability, interaction-design

[image]

Im creating a new feature to allow users to add a new comment field into their online table. For various technology reasons we are using a small modal when entering comments.

The comments will be limited to 250 characters (for other reasons). My question is:

- Should i prevent users from entering in characters over 250? or
- Should i allow users to enter in characters over 250 but prevent them from submitting it and display characters which will not be submitted (similar to how twitter allows you to do this?)

Answer (score 0):

The Twitter way is much more helpful.

It's easier to type the entire comment (to get it all down regardless of size) and then edit it and remove any excess words without losing the intent of your message -- than typing up to the limit and then having to edit the comment which is not yet complete because you still have more to add.

Hitting the 250 limit before you've finished the comment could make users delete the entire thing and start again.